# Match multiple lines of a file and replace if content does not match

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a particular file(sample.txt) say with content :

```
Doc=True    
Add=123.566.33.8    
This #is a sample File    
Use #for Certain specific functions    
Domain=443.59.43.23
```

Upon performing a certain operation, the content of this file changes :

```
Doc=True
Add=123.566.33.8
eshfsjfn
sldfhsehfoewjwefn
lsjdnfnfd
```

Now I need to make sure that the content always remains as in the first case. 
So I'm trying to grep the initial pattern(sample.txt) using a certain grep command with all the required lines and if in case the lines do not match, then it should append these lines in the file sample.txt . 
The content in sample.txt should always be limited to what is shown initially. I don't want to create another file with the same content and then match them. 
I want to use grep, sed or perhaps awk.

Comment: first, please. You said you have "sample.txt" and it changes it content. You also say you don´t want to create another file with the same content. Then... what you want to match?? If your file has changed it´s content,.... with what will you match it?¿? Where did the data you lost gone?? Maybe you need something that will check for the changes ?? or you mean something like `diff sample.txt sample2txt` ???

Comment: I don't want to create another file with the same content and then match them. <- what file or data should be compared then?

Comment: I want to use grep something like this. 


egrep "Doc=True|Add=123.566.33.8|This #is a sample File|Use #for Certain specific functions|Domain=443.59.43.23" sample.txt 


I don't want to keep this original code anywhere in a seperate file. Need to grep all the original lines and check if the file after certain operation has changed. If yes, simply append append the original content back to this file.

Comment: but what do you want to match with?¿?¿?¿??¿ The line with what?¿?¿¿?¿??¿¿?¿??¿¿?¿?¿?

You say I Need to grep all the original lines and check if the file after certain operation has changed.

Then, at that moment, if you´ve just CHANGED the file, you DON´T have the ORIGINAL lines. Then you CANNOT check it.  You MUST save your file BEFORE IT CHANGES (in memory or in a new file) and then check AGAINST IT. This way you´ll generate a new file to compare. Anyway you´ll be able to rewrite the file in awk. Did you tried the code i posted?¿ maybe a little more clear example could help us.

Comment: Take away write permissions on the file: `chmod a-w filename`

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer assuming you want sample.txt to be checked against an standar awk file entrance

Hope it can help you

```
awk'BEGIN {
  while (getline < "sample.txt")
  {
    a[$0]
  }
}
{
    if( $0 in a)
    {
        located=true;
    }
    if(!located)
    {
        print "Line changed ->"NR" ->"$0
        print $0 >> "sample.txt"  <-- Printing located line in sample.txt
        located=false;
    }
}' file2.dat
```

Comment: This will save the file into an awk array, which index is the whole line ($0), Then with `$0 in a` we´ll check if the line is in the array. And if it´s not there, it will be printed as a changed line.  

file2.dat could be substituted by a pipe before the awk  (for example:) `your_command.sh | awk '{[...]}'`

Comment: If you want this lines to be written in "sample.txt", just add `>> "sample.txt"` to the print commands in awk. This will add the lines directly to the file